# How to perform an if then for each instance of a variable in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I am trying to set NA values in a dataframe to 0 if the id for the row is included in a separate list, but am getting either nothing (no changes no error), or this error:

```
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Here is how my data is structured:

```
   id out1 in1 bet1  
   1    6   0    0     
  10   NA  NA   NA      
 100    7  14    0
```

So, if the id 10 was in the separate vector, I would want those values reset to zero.

My code is below. Any help is appreciated!

```
if(is.na(dset_n$bet3) && dset_n$id %in% unique(net_t3[,1])) {
  dset_n$bet3 <- 0
}
```

Solution:

```
dset_n$m <- dset_n$id %in% unique(net_t2[,1])
dset_n$out2[dset_n$m & is.na(dset_n$out2)] <- 0
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible data instead of just showing what it looks like. You can give R code to create the data, use a built-in dataset, or `dput` the data.

Comment: `if` is used for evaluating a comparison that returns a single logical value like `if(1==1)` not comparing vectors like `if(c(1,2,3)==c(1,2,3))`

Comment: Ah got it. I am trying to create a Boolean vector now that I can use to know when a variable should be recoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what your attempted solution is trying to do, but based on your verbal description I would do this:

```
net_t3 <- cbind(c(10, 20))
 dset_n <- read.table(text='id out1 in1 bet1
   1    6   0    0
  10   NA  1   NA
 100    7  14    0', header=T)
m <- dset_n$id %in% net_t3[, 1]
dset_n[m,is.na(dset_n[m,])] <- 0
```

Comment: Thank you! I made the m vector and tried to write code to fix my data (I don't fully understand the last line), but no changes are happening. This is what I did:                                                                     dset_n$out3[is.na(dset_n$id) & dset_n$m == TRUE] <- 0

Comment: I've renamed the variables in my answer to correspond (I think) to your example. Does that help?

Comment: To understand the last line, break it apart. Look at `dset_n[m,]`, and `is.na(dset_n[m,])` separately. Understand how the pieces work and then figure out how they fit together.

Comment: dset_n$out3[m,is.na(dset_n$out3[m,])] <- 0
Error in dset_n$out3[m, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: It looks like the command is saying that, for the variable I want to change, in rows m (true/false), if the column is NA then change the variable.

Comment: This worked! dset_n$out3[dset_n$m & is.na(dset_n$out3)] <- 0